# Getting "No Answer" When I Test If The Chipset Is Injectable Or Not?

Tags: aircrack-ng

When I tried this command `aireplay-ng --test wlan0` I got This :

```
 01:10:49  Trying broadcast probe requests...
 01:10:51  No Answer...
 01:10:51  Found 2 APs

 01:10:51  Trying directed probe requests...
 01:10:51  72:EC:E4:3D:6E:28 - channel: 6 - 'Black Hawk'
 01:10:57   0/30:   0%

 01:10:57  10:FE:ED:6A:AB:D8 - channel: 6 - 'max'
 01:11:03   0/30:   0%
```

Is that mean the the network card is not injectable and I have to buy another ?
or this mean there is a problem should I fix to be it injectable ?

Note: I am using Ubuntu `16.04` and with kernel version `4.4.0-47-generic` and the `Realtek RTL8101/2/6E` adapter

Comment: Monitor Mode enabled?
airmon-ng start wlan0/ or wlan1

Comment: Try this `aireplay-ng -9 wlan0`. You can replace **9** with any other channels like **`1,6&11`**.